# Can I mix varnishes from the same product line?

Tags: varnishing

I tried to match colour with the original floor varnish but the original varnish falls between light oak and antique pine in the Ronseal [range](https://www.ronseal.com/products/diamond-hard-floor-varnish/).

[image]

Can I mix two varnishes from the same manufacturer to darker the lighter varnish in a 1:2 ratio or is there any incomptibility to mix in such a manner?

Comment: Are you trying to match a repair/patch section or the whole floor?  Stuff fades or darkens over time, so even the exact same shade of new varnish will usually not match what the old floor varnish looks like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I emailed Ronseal as I couldn't find a source in the answer by JACK who was 100% correct.  This is the answer I got:

> Ronseal Diamond Hard Floor Varnish colours can be mixed, providing you
> are mixing exactly the same range of products.
>
> We wouldn't recommend to mix different ranges as this would result
> with performance and finish issues.
>
> Kamil Ronseal Customer Service

Comment: Note that there is no worry about anything becoming "toxic" (so long as you're not drinking it...)

Answer (score 6):

From the same manufacturer and the same type it will work. I've done this many times. Be prepared to do a lot of mixing and testing on sample pieces of wood and waiting for them to dry completely before doing your actual project.

Comment: Yep. Testing to completion is the real trick here. +1

Comment: Thanks, is there any source to say it won't become toxic if mixed?

Comment: @SeanJ  Not that I know of but that's why you have to use the same the same manufacturer and the same type.  Then the pigment or dyes are the only difference.